# Github Action: Trigger a workflow from another branch

Tags: github

I have two branches: `feat` and `master`.
`feat` doesn't have a .github folder.
`master` has one with the following trigger:

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - feat
```

When I push something on `feat`, the workflow on the `master` branch isn't triggered. Is there any away around it ?